# Could not start GlassFish server 4.1.1 : administrator port is occupied by exception

Tags: linux, netbeans, glassfish-4.1, netbeans-8.2

I've CentOS 6.4 as server and client in VMs. I installed GlassFish server successfully in server. Now I want to connect NetBeans 8.2 client to GlassFish server. I found this error :-

> could not start glassfish server 4.1.1 : administrator port is occupied by exception while processing command: org.glassfigh.internal.api.RemoteAdminAccessException

After Googling, I removed the server from the IDE and tried to add server again. This time I entered `/usr/local/glassfish-4.1.1` at the server location but I am confused with local domain and remote domain. If I want to connect with GlassFish server ( on a CentOS server ) how to do that?

Comment: is netbenas runing on the same server as glassfish? if so then it is a local domain.

Comment: ok but how to connect client java netbeans  to remote glassfish server

Comment: you click the remote switch and put the server ip or hostname with the port glassfish is running on. Along with the user info for logining as a admin. Make sure you glassfish server is enabled for remote admin access.

Comment: i did as you said :-
right click on servers -> add server -> glassfish server -> install location : /usr/local/glassfish-4.1.1, clicked on remote location -> next -> domain : doamin1, host: serverora11gr2.db.net, DAS port : 4848,  http Port : 8080, user name : admin, password : passwd -> finish

but after right click in glassfish in service pane -> there is start, stop restart are inactive. what to do next.

Comment: is you server enabled for remote admin?

Answer (score 0):

i did like this :-

```
./asadmin change-admin-password
./asadmin enable-secure-admin
./asadmin stop-domain
./asadmin start-domain
```

but it has no effect